# Vertically center flex container on page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

I am currently trying to vertically center a flex container on a page.

I have a row of 4 circles that I would like to display in the middle of the page. However, the regular method of doing

```
margin:0;
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
```

throws away the flex and displays the circles incorrectly. Does anybody know how to make this work with flex?

Here is example code, HTML:

```
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circles {
  background: red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  width: 500px;
}

.circle {
  width: 124px;
  height: 124px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

Output: [image]

I would like for the red area with the white circles to be displayed in the center of the page.
Thanks in advance to those who respond.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: @MarioG8 Yeah, the answer I marked as correct helped me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've missed is the height of the "circles" class.
Because without that, the browser can't know where to align them vertically. Below is the snippet code.

```css
.circles {
  background: red;
  display:flex;justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;
  align-items:center;
  height:100vh;
}

.circle {
  width: 124px;
  height: 124px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content inside a `div` and apply `display:flex` to it, then give this `div` the entire viewport height and align it's content to center.

(in case that you want to keep the red background behind the circles only not the entire page)

```css
.cont{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circles {
  background: red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  width: 500px;
  
}

.circle {
  width: 124px;
  height: 124px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="circles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can simple add `body` selector as main container and use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) properties  with `align-items: center;` to center vertically and  `justify-content: center;` to center horizontally, remembering about the `height: 100vh` property.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circles {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
}

.circle {
  width: 124px;
  height: 124px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the margin property to auto to horizontally center the element within its container.

Give circles' container, a `height` and `display: flex;` and the margin will vertically center too.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.circles {
  background: red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle {
  width: 124px;
  height: 124px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```